# Microsoft TFS source control - How to source two projects independently?

Tags: c#, tfs

Can I use separate TFS source control for two projects under the same solution?  More specifically...

I have a project, "Shared", which contains a library of my custom functions that I use across many different projects.  I'm constantly updating it and moving generic code into this library to recycle later.

Another project, "MyProject", represents my current on-going work.  This is specific to the project of the day, and I have many different ones.

What's the best method to allow separate source control for each project, while allowing them to run under the same solution?

**EDIT 1** 
I'd like to be able to edit the two projects simultaneously under different source control.

Based on the comments, it seems like I'm thinking about this in the wrong way.  Perhaps what I can do is to have two solutions each with a single project under different source control.  When I want to edit my "Shared" project, I'll flip to the "Shared" solution, make the edits and create the dll.  The second project "MyProject" will link to the dll.  This sounds like a hack though!

Comment: If this is even possible, I suspect it would cause more problems than it solves.  Would multiple solutions "own" this same shared code?  In the case of this shared code I imagine the standard approach would be either to bring the projects into the same solution (why not do that?), or to keep the shared code in its own solution which builds separately and deploys as a consumable library for other solutions.  (Possibly as a self-hosted NuGet package, that would be pretty cool.  But a distributable DLL works just as well.)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @David I tried to describe your suggestion in my own words.  If you think this is the way to go you can write it as an answer.